# Calculate area under each class for a feature in a shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, area, classification

I have a shapefile that you see in attached picture and you can see it has eight classes for a feature shown in picture. How do I calculate area under each class. I would like to export area information in dataframe/CSV/shapefile because I have multiple shapefiles to run. Or, maybe, calculate number of pixels under each class? I have tried using GeoPandas in Python. I have also tried few tools in QGIS but I can not find any way so far.

[image]

I tried this on geodataframe and it gives me wrong area, lot of duplication.

```
county1["area_pct"] = (county1.area / county1.area.sum()) *100
county1_grp = county1.groupby(['feature'])['area_pct'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Area  is a property of vector formats, but is meaningless in geographic coordinate references. Rasters have pixels (but, again, pixel size is meaningless). There exist geodesic area calculation functions, or you can reproject to an equal-area CRS.

Comment: How do i re-project to equal-area CRS, can you please elaborate?

Comment: i mean which CRS projection do you recommend for equal area CRS?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, right click on your layer, `Open attribute table` -> `Toggle editing mode` -> `Open field calculator`, add a new field called area, then in the expression search for area, click on `$area`. This will add the area for each attribute you have in your shapefile.

Comment: what units i will get? how do make sure that i get specific units like acres/km sq.?

Comment: It will be in whatever units your project is in. To check this, when you search for area, look at the 'project_area_units' under the variables heading. It will show you what the units will be on the right pane. Alternatively right click your layer, go to properties, go to information, under the coordinate reference system will be the units. If I answered your question please mark as answered - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: actually this is giving me area in decimal degress as i have espg 4326. i need a way to calculate it in acres or m sq.

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the information when you right click your layer, go to properties and show the information.

Comment: just posted the screenshot as my answer. it was not allowing me to post screenshot here in comment.

Comment: No problems, next time add it to the bottom of your question by clicking 'edit'. Okay so You need to reproject your layer into a different CRS. Right click your layer, go to layer CRS, then set CRS, and filter to the CRS of your choice. Then repeat the above step to calculate the area because i'm not sure if it recalculates it automatically.

Comment: I think you'll need to dissolve before calculating the area or use the aggregate tool grouping by the field with the class information and summing the area of each feature.